# URL Rewriting and GET values

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know there are lots of answer about this, but I can't understand why it does not work for me.

I want every URL like :

```
http://mywebsite.com/campagne/blabla
```

to be redirected to

```
http://mywebsite.com/campagne.php?c=blabla
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule campagne/(.+)$  campagne.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]   [L]
```

The URL is redirected to campagne.php but $_GET['c'] is not sent.

Can you help me? I cannot find what is wrong? It works on my local server but not online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to enabling of `MultiViews` option in your Apache. Place this line on top of your .htaccess to turn it off:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.